# python: `with` statement in anonymous functions

Tags: python, anonymous-function

Is it possible to use `with` statement in Python anonymous functions? For example, I have a function that writes `1` to a file:

```
def write_one(filename):
    with open(filename, 'wt') as fp:
        fp.write('1')
```

But this function is to be organized in a dict:

```
my_functions = {
    ....
}
```

Obviously I can write this statement to add this function to the dict:

```
my_functions['write_one'] = write_one
```

But the problem is the name `write_one` still exists in the current scope. How can I introduce an anonymous function without polluting the current namespace?

For simple functions, I can use `lambda`. For slightly complicated functions, I can return a tuple to execute multiple statements (to be precise, expressions). But I didn't find a way to cleverly use `lambda` so that it can work with `with` statements. If this is impossible, where it says so in its documentation?

The solution with a `del write_one` doesn't look good to me. I don't want this name to be introduced at all in the current namespace.

In a word, what I want is something like this:

```
my_functions['write_one'] = def(filename):
    with open(filename, 'wt') as fp:
        fp.write('1')
```

This is kind of awkward with Python's indentation-based rules, I know. But it does its job.

Comment: No, it is not. `lambda` expressions can only contain *expressions*, not statements.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is `lambda` the only way to construct an anonymous function in Python? I'm talking about anonymous functions not `lambda`.

Comment: Yes, it is. I rarely use `lambda` expressions, only when I'm being super lazy, or for very simple one-offs that I pass to a higher-order function like `map`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So where in the doc it says *lambda is the only way to construct an anonymous functions*?

Comment: It doesn't say that anywhere in the docs. But you can conclude that by elimination. If you don't believe me, you are free to search the docs for another methd.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Obviously I haven't found another way to do so but *by elimination* means reading all the docs, peps. Not really feasible.

Comment: Yes. or you could just believe people with experience in the language. Up to you.

Comment: I would re-phrase your title. The question seems to center around "How to hide complex functions from the global namespace without using another module?" or something akin to that.

Comment: @kabanus The question is really about how to create an anonymous function and put its reference in a dict but not the current namespace. Otherwise we can just use `def` to define that function.

Comment: So the requirement is using lambda? Hiding/not creating the function in/from the global namespace is not enough?

Comment: @kabanus No, you can use anything you can think of, if Python allows it.

Comment: I guess I am asking if my answer does not cover it? I explicitly do not use `lambda`s.

Comment: That last comment makes it seem like you do not care about using anonymous functions (that is an explicit term for `lambda` function).

Comment: @kabanus The essence of this question is that `lambda` doesn't allow statements. Compare this to JavaScript anonymous functions which almost allow you to do anything.

Comment: OK, then @juanpa has your answer.

Comment: @Cyker yeah man. I don't know what other type of answer you want, but Python anonymous functions are very restricted. Indeed, Guido wanted to flat-out eliminate them in the transition to Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambda expressions are quite restricted in what they can do. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

> Note that functions created with lambda expressions cannot contain statements or annotations.

Just use a full function definition. If you really want to avoid polluting the namespace, just `del` the name afterwards.

Or if you simply want to avoid the module namespace from having a bunch of these small functions for code-completion purposes, use `_` in the front of the function name.

If you truly want to avoid it, you *could* use the `function` constructor and dynamically compile code, etc. Or use some other kind of dynamic code execution, e.g. using `eval` or `exec`. But that is almost certainly not worth the trouble. 
 Especially if you can just `del` the name after you are done using it.

Or perhaps the best approach is to put all these functions in another namespace, like another module.

Comment: By the way, and I by no means endorse this, and it may annoy you slightly, there is a hack around this - using `exec`. Now that's a recipe for bugs! Or deleting the hard-drive for that matter.

Comment: @kabanus sure, I had added these sorts of highly hacky options as edits.

Comment: Ah I see now - disagree a bit that a "function in a function" is hacky, but the rest I agree with completely.

Comment: @kabanus I didn't mean that, I mean using `eval`, `exec` or the `function` constructor

Answer (score 1):

There are not many namespaces in Python - a function is basically the local one. That gives a good hint to a possible solution:

```
def gen_functions():
    def f1(i):
        print(i)
    def f2(i):
        print(i+1)
    return f1,f2

my_funcs = dict(zip(('a','b'),gen_functions()))
my_funcs['a'](2)
my_funcs['b'](7)
f1(3)
```

Run this:

```
>py bla.py
2
8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bla.py", line 11, in <module>
    f1(3)
NameError: name 'f1' is not defined
```

So you can make arbitrarily complex functions - to hide them from the global namespace you just enclose them in another function.